# Why does this timestampdiff CASE yield AVG lower than the WHEN?

Tags: mysql, reporting

I am trying to get an average uninstall date by source report going, i have a

```
select i.source,u.avgday from inst i
left join ( select u.app_uid,
  case 
    when timestampdiff(day,i.app_installed_datetime, u.timestamp) > 3
    then timestampdiff(day,i.app_installed_datetime, u.timestamp) 
   else null end as avgday
  from uninst u
  inner join inst i
  on i.app_uid = u.app_uid
) as u
on u.app_uid = i.app_uid
group by i.source
```

Why am I getting a u.avgday result in the 0.1-10 range? Shouldnt this only AVG where theres a value, else its Null?

Comment: You're not calling AVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `AVG()` aggregate function like

```
  avg(case 
    when timestampdiff(day,i.app_installed_datetime, u.timestamp) > 3
    then timestampdiff(day,i.app_installed_datetime, u.timestamp) 
    end) as avgday
```

Comment: stupid mistake - thanks. Yes, i spaced out when redoing the query